# Adding Pushpins to map from ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, bing-maps, pushpin

I try to add multiple Pushpins to my map but they dont appear on the Map!
As I figure out when I remove the DataTemplate Tag I see the Pin with it nothing!

My XAML Code:

```
 <Window x:Class="Maps_test.AddPushpinToMap"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Maps_test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
     Width="1024" Height="768">


<Grid Name="Main">
    <m:Map x:Name="myMap" 
           CredentialsProvider=" -" 
           Mode="AerialWithLabels" 
           Center="54.13,12.1004289" 
           ZoomLevel="12"
           MouseDoubleClick="MapWithPushpins_MouseDoubleClick">

        <m:MapItemsControl x:Name="PushpinCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding PushpinList}">
            <m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <m:Pushpin  Background="#FFB6DE2E" Tag="{Binding Tag}" Visibility="{Binding Show}">
                        <m:Location Latitude="{Binding Latitude}" Longitude="{Binding Longitude}" />
                    </m:Pushpin>
                </DataTemplate>
            </m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </m:MapItemsControl>

        <Button x:Name="button" Click="addImageToMap" Opacity="0.8" Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="10,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78">
            <TextBlock><Run Text="Show Image"/></TextBlock>
        </Button>
    </m:Map>
    <Grid x:Name="menugrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Width="{Binding ElementName=Main,Path=ActualWidth}"  Margin="0,-1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <Menu x:Name="menu" Margin="0,2,-4,0">
            <Menu.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0C0909" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Menu.Background>
            <Label x:Name="label" Content="Rostocker Stadteil : " Height="23" Width="118" Foreground="#FFF9F4F4" FontFamily="Arial" Margin="0,10,0,0"  />
            <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" SelectionChanged="ChangeMapView_SelectionChanged" Height="23" Width="160" Margin="0,8,0,0">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Seebad Warnemünde" Tag="54.1725,12.0828,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Diedrichshagen" Tag="54.171836,12.033028,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Markgrafenheide" Tag="54.190279,12.157802,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Hohe Düne" Tag="54.177790,12.116995,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Hinrichshagen" Tag="54.207616,12.196298,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Wiethagen" Tag="54.202428,12.252413,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Torfbrügge" Tag="54.233147,12.224683,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Lichtenhagen" Tag="54.155347,12.047310,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Groß Klein" Tag="54.149608,12.080472,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Lütten Klein" Tag="54.138211,12.052280,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Evershagen" Tag="54.118766,12.053579,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Schmarl" Tag="54.127447,12.080520,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Reutershagen" Tag="54.098111,12.072783,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Hansavirtel" Tag="54.084673,12.097592,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Gartenstadt/Stadtweide" Tag="54.076974,12.078598,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Kröpeliner-Tor-Vorstadt" Tag="54.095194,12.106574,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Südstadt" Tag="54.070748,12.121374,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Biestow" Tag="54.060217,12.098262,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Stadtmitte" Tag="54.085435,12.141921,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Brinkmansdorf" Tag="54.087047,12.175463,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Dierkow" Tag="54.100835,12.162007,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Toitenwinkel" Tag="54.116951,12.141470,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Gehldorf" Tag="54.104504,12.120084,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Hinrichsdorf" Tag="54.132611,12.158463,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Krummendorf" Tag="54.128727,12.121321,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Nienhagen" Tag="54.147796,12.173734,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Peez" Tag="54.148566,12.125750,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Stuthof" Tag="54.166652,12.173001,0 15"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Jürgeshof" Tag="54.177121,12.189099,0 15"/>
            </ComboBox>
            <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Umkreis :" Height="23" Width="64" Foreground="#FFF9F4F4" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
            <Slider x:Name="Distance" Width="100" BorderThickness="0,10,0,0" Value="1"/>
            <Canvas Height="33" Width="265" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <ComboBox x:Name="EntityType" SelectionChanged="ShowPins_SelectionChanged" Height="23" Canvas.Left="98" Canvas.Top="10" Width="129">
                    <ComboBoxItem Tag="7011" IsSelected="True" >Hotels</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Tag="5800" >Tourist Attractions</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Tag="7999" >Restaurants</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
                <Label x:Name="label2" Content="POIS:" Height="23" Canvas.Left="11" Canvas.Top="10" Width="71" Foreground="Gray"/>
            </Canvas>

        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

PushpinViewModel Code

```
     public sealed partial class MainPage : Window
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            PushpinViewModel pvm = new PushpinViewModel();
            pvm.PushpinList = new ObservableCollection<PushpinClass>();

            pvm.PushpinList.Add(new PushpinClass() { Latitude = 54.090604, Longitude = 12.147961, Tag = "5800", Show = Visibility.Visible });
            pvm.PushpinList.Add(new PushpinClass() { Latitude = 54.1581419, Longitude = 12.0763132, Tag = "7999", Show = Visibility.Visible });
            pvm.PushpinList.Add(new PushpinClass() { Latitude = 14f, Longitude = 12.0763132, Tag = "7011", Show = Visibility.Visible });
            DataContext = pvm;
        }
    }

    class PushpinViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PushpinClass> PushpinList { get; set; }
    }

    class PushpinClass
    {
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public Visibility Show { get; set; }
        public ToolTip Tip { get; set; }

  }
```

My MAINWINDOW.XAML.CS CODE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Design;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;

namespace Maps_test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
       public partial class MainWindow : Window
       {
           public MainWindow()
           {

           }
       }

    public enum TagInfo { Hotels = 7011, Restaurants = 7999, TouristAttractions = 5800 }
    public partial class AddPushpinToMap : Window
    {
        LocationConverter locConverter = new LocationConverter();
        string BingMapsKey = "_";

        public AddPushpinToMap()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Set focus on mapl
            myMap.Focus();
        }



        private void MapWithPushpins_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // Disables the default mouse double-click action.
            e.Handled = true;

            // Determin the location to place the pushpin at on the map.

            //Get the mouse click coordinates
            Point mousePosition = e.GetPosition(this);
            //Convert the mouse coordinates to a locatoin on the map
            Location pinLocation = myMap.ViewportPointToLocation(mousePosition);

            // The pushpin to add to the map.
            Pushpin pin = new Pushpin(); 
            pin.Location = pinLocation;

            // Adds the pushpin to the map.
            myMap.Children.Add(pin);
        }

        private void addImageToMap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MapLayer imageLayer = new MapLayer();


            Image image = new Image();
            image.Height = 150;
            //Define the URI location of the image
            BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
            myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/Dortmund_Petrikirche.jpg/220px-Dortmund_Petrikirche.jpg");
            // To save significant application memory, set the DecodePixelWidth or  
            // DecodePixelHeight of the BitmapImage value of the image source to the desired 
            // height or width of the rendered image. If you don't do this, the application will 
            // cache the image as though it were rendered as its normal size rather then just 
            // the size that is displayed.
            // Note: In order to preserve aspect ratio, set DecodePixelWidth
            // or DecodePixelHeight but not both.
            //Define the image display properties
            myBitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 150;
            myBitmapImage.EndInit();
            image.Source = myBitmapImage;
            image.Opacity = 0.6;
            image.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None;

            //The map location to place the image at
            Location location = new Location() { Latitude = 54.090604, Longitude = 12.147961 };
            //Center the image around the location specified
            PositionOrigin position = PositionOrigin.Center;

            //Add the image to the defined map layer
            imageLayer.AddChild(image, location, position);
            //Add the image layer to the map
            myMap.Children.Add(imageLayer);
       }

        private void viewMap_ViewChangeOnFrame(object sender, MapEventArgs e)
        {
            // Gets the map object that raised this event.
            Map map = sender as Map;
            // Determine if we have a valid map object.
            if (map != null)
            {
                // Gets the center of the current map view for this particular frame.
                Location mapCenter = map.Center;

             /*   // Updates the latitude and longitude values, in real time,
                // as the map animates to the new location.
                txtLatitude.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                  "{0:F5}", mapCenter.Latitude);
                txtLongitude.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "{0:F5}", mapCenter.Longitude);*/
            }
        }


        private void ChangeMapView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)(((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem);

            // Parse the information of the Combobox Tag property
            string[] tagInfo = cbi.Tag.ToString().Split(' ');
            Location center = (Location)locConverter.ConvertFrom(tagInfo[0]);
            double zoom = System.Convert.ToDouble(tagInfo[1]);

            // Set the map view
            myMap.SetView(center, zoom);
        }

        // Geocode an address and return a latitude and longitude
        public XmlDocument Geocode(string addressQuery)
        {
            //Create REST Services geocode request using Locations API
            string geocodeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/" + addressQuery + "?o=xml&key=" + BingMapsKey;

            //Make the request and get the response
            XmlDocument geocodeResponse = GetXmlResponse(geocodeRequest);

            return (geocodeResponse);
        }


        // Submit a REST Services or Spatial Data Services request and return the response
        private XmlDocument GetXmlResponse(string requestUrl)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Request URL (XML): " + requestUrl);
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
                    response.StatusCode,
                    response.StatusDescription));
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
                return xmlDoc;
            }
        }

        public void ShowPins_SelectionChanged(object sender,  SelectionChangedEventArgs e)


// Is part is not ready 
        {
            ComboBoxItem pin = (ComboBoxItem)(((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem);

            string tagInfo = pin.Tag.ToString();

            switch(tagInfo)
            {
                case "7011":



                    break; 
            }
        } 

    }
```

I already looked for solutions but all i found doesnt work.
plz Help!!

Answer (score 0):

MapItemsControl inherits from ItemsControl class, so you have to bind ItemsSource property:

```
<m:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PushpinList}"/>
```

EDIT:
Apart of the above you have to make your classes public:

```
public class PushpinViewModel{...}
public class PushpinClass{...}
```

Comment: Thanks! forget to insert the line in the code above didnt work.

Comment: Hey @Roland! class PushpinViewModel and class PushpinClass should be public. Remenber that by default in c# all class are private unless you specified another scope (public, protected)

Comment: Oh havent seen it! Thanks! changing classes to public didnt solve the problem ;(

Comment: Are you re-defining DataContext at some level in the visual tree?

Comment: I have no idea sorry i am a beginner ;)

Comment: No problem, can you post the entire MainPage xaml?

Comment: The only clue I have is an Exception XamlParseException: "Binding" can not set the Proberty "Longitude" from Typ "Location". "Binding" can only be set as "DependencyProperty" of an "DependencyObject" .

Comment: What do you have in those combobox SelectionChanged? Your xaml seems to be fine but the binding error leads me to think that you are redefining the binding in some point of your execution logic.

Comment: I posted the whole MainWindow.xaml.cs maybe my error in in there somewhere ;(

Comment: In the combobox is an selection of coordinates when you chose one of the Items in the box the map jumps to the destination